# Matrices : Show that $E_{p,q}\cdot E_{k,l}=\delta_{q,k}\cdot E_{p,l}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> We note $ E_{p,q}\in M_n[X]$ (with $p,q\in [\![1,n]\!]$) one matrix such that $e_{\,p,\,q}=1$ otherwise $e_{i,j}=$0
>
> Show that $E_{p,q}\cdot E_{k,l}=\delta_{q,k}\cdot E_{p,l}$

Attempt :

$E_{p,q}=\delta_{i,p}\cdot \delta_{j,q}$ and $E_{k,l}=\delta_{i,k}\cdot \delta_{j,l}$

then $\displaystyle E_{p,q}\cdot E_{k,l}=\sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(\delta_{i,p}\cdot \delta_{j,q}\cdot \delta_{i,k}\cdot \delta_{j,l}\bigg)=\delta_{i,p}\cdot \delta_{q,q}\cdot \delta_{i,k}\cdot \delta_{q,l}=\delta_{i,p}\cdot \delta_{i,k}\cdot \delta_{q,l}$

I really don't know how to find the result expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E_{ij} = e_i e_j^T$.

Then $E_{pq} E_{kl} = e_p e_q^T e_k e_l^T = (e_q^T e_k) e_p e_l^T = \delta_{q k} E_{pl}$.

Comment: I don't understand this notation, do you mean that $e_j=\big [e_1,...,e_j,...,e_n\big]$

Comment: understood  thanks

Comment: $e_k$ is the (column) vector of zeros with one in the $k$th place.

Comment: Sorry, but I came back on your explanation, beacuse I don't understand. I know that $E_{p,q}=C^q\cdot L^p$ but why do you use the transpose of a column vector

Comment: @Stu: I don't understand your question. The $E_{ij}$ matrix is a a dyad formed by multiplying a column vector by a row vector.

Comment: Yes like that $E_{p,q}=C^q\cdot L^p$, but when you write $e_k$ is the column vector, I don t understand that $E_{ij} = e_i e_j^T$, $e_i$ seems to be a column vector, and all its elements are equal to $0$

Comment: No, $e_i$ is a vector of zeros except for a one in the $i$th place.

Comment: $E_{i,j}$ means 1 at $i$ th line and at the $j$th column if you use the vector column $e_i$, you are taking the i $th$ column, so you will find $1$ in your column only if $i=j$

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking a question or making a statement. We have $E_{ij} = e_i e_j^T$.

Comment: ok it's fine, I will post a new question